# Can't resolve class dependencies in a MAVEN project with Child/Modules (seen in Eclipse and mnv CLI)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have an Eclipse Maven Project (parent) that hosts three Maven MODULES (it's children). Only the child MODULES have code under "src/main/java/..." (i.e. the PARENT is just a stub place holder for the children).
Each MODULE is independent of one another... I just set it up that way to reduce clutter. =:)

Now the project structure didn't start out this way. Initially it was just one big PARENT and no child MODULES; and everything worked fine. But then I reorganized things within Eclipse (again to reduce clutter) using various **moves/refactors**, and things stopped working.

**The Problem**: My source code can't find imported classes now, so my dependency resolution became problematic somewhere. And the problem isn't just seen in Eclipse, but also when I run, say, 'mvn clean install' from the CLI. So I suspect something is wrong with the set of POM files that resulted from my moves/refactors.

Here they are (the PARENT and one CHILD). Am I missing something, or is something incorrect? Maybe I should check something Eclipse, too?
Note that I embedded a couple of little in-line questions inside the POM files below. :)

The **PARENT** pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>someName</name>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <groupId>someParentGroupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>someParentArtifactId</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
     <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>

     <example-core.version>0.9.3</example-core.version>
     <!-- Intended to be used by some Child/Module.
          I hope PARENT/CHILD POM inheritance works that way? -->
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
     <!-- Dependencies are all in the Children/Modules -->
  </dependencies>


  <!-- ################### BUILD SETTINGS BEGIN ##################### -->
  <build>
     <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.2</version>
              <configuration>
                 <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                 <target>${jdk.version}</target>
              </configuration>
           </plugin>
        </plugins>
     </pluginManagement>

     <plugins>
        <plugin> <!-- Used to create an UBER/FAT-JAR. -->
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3</version>
           <executions>
              <execution>
                 <phase>package</phase>
                 <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                 </goals>
              </execution>
           </executions>
           <configuration>
              <finalName>uber-${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>
  <!-- ################### BUILD SETTINGS END ####################### -->

  <modules>
     <module>childModule1</module>
     <module>childModule2</module>
     <module>chileModule3</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

Example **CHILD** **pom.xml** file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
     <groupId>someParentGroupId</groupId>
     <artifactId>someParentArtifactId</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>someChildArtifactId</artifactId>

  <!-- I noticed this missing in the Children/Module POM. Is that okay?
     <name>
     </name>
  -->

  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.example.somgGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>example-core</artifactId>
        <version>${example-core.version}</version>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Again, the problem seems simple. I can't resolve imports (so, naturally, my Classes have import-ralated errors).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: has anybody solved this issue? I am having the same problem now

Answer (score 0):

name is not a mandatory attribute in pom.xml.

I assume someChildArtifactId is given as an example. If not, the same artifact id should be used in the parent pom.